# FRED Users: How do you retrieve which series were updated today?

Tags: python, r

If you use FRED (https://fred.stlouisfed.org), you may have encountered the following situation: you have a data set of multiple series (say, 100 series), and you only want to retrieve those series that were updated in a specific timeframe (e.g. you check daily, and you **only** want to retrieve those series of your 100 that were updated today).

Fred offers the function *fred/series/updates*, described here in detail: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/series_updates.html

But, the series has a max. limit of 1000 results (or series), and once you use the function, you quickly realize that a typical call will return considerably more than 1000 results.

So, my question for FRED users: has anyone a good idea how to leverage this function? I'd really like to avoid having to do repeated calls to return the full list of updates (which one could do, I suppose, leveraging the "offset" parameter, but the volume of results returned defies the idea of minimizing data downloads). To the best of my knowledge you cannot pass a series of mnemonics and ask which of these have been updated.

So - what are ways you have found helpful for using *fred/series/updates*?

Thanks, Philipp

PS I'm leveraging R, but I suppose that the same issue may arise if you use python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a great answer here but there are some approaches that likely limit the number of calls you have to theoretically make.

Based on their API documentation, it seems you have no choice but to loop through all the results using the `offset` parameter.

- You could limit results using the filter parameter if you know, a priori, that you are only interested in certain things. This isn't as ideal as being able to specify *specific* mnemonics, but it can help!
- The docs say it limits to the last 2 weeks of updates and the results are sorted by the last update. If you track updates daily, you likely never have to go past "the first offset" on any given day (past the "genesis day") except on days the release is particularly large.

Do not take this as legal advice (I have not read their TOS)... but I do not think the total volume of calls you theoretically would make even if you downloaded the last 2 weeks of data daily would be considered "excessive" (in the grand scheme of things, even a few thousand JSON objects w/ 1000 entries each, as documented, isn't going to have an adverse effect on their bandwidth, especially if you rate limit your requests). That said, you can likely save yourself a large volume of calls.